# why does it detect the connection to the database as undefined?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, express

I'm making a basic API but don't understand why it gives me an error.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'conneDB' of undefined`

```
import { json, Request, Response } from "express";


import { ConnectionDB } from "../ConnectionDB";
import  Post  from "../interfaces/Ipost.interface";


export class PostsController {
    private conneDB = new ConnectionDB()


async getAllPosts(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const posts = await this.conneDB.connection.query('SELECT * FROM posts')
    return res.json(posts[0])
}

async getPost(req: Request, res: Response){
    const idPost = req.params.postId;
    const post = await this.conneDB.connection.query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ?', [idPost])
    return res.json(post[0])
}

async createPost(req: Request, res: Response) : Promise<Response>{
    const newPost: Post = req.body;
    await this.conneDB.connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', [newPost])
    return res.json({
        message: 'Post created'
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Possible to share the code of `ConnectionDB.ts` file?

Comment: `import { createPool } from 'mysql2/promise';

export class ConnectionDB {
    
    connection;

    constructor(){
        this.connection = createPool({
            'host': 'localhost',
            'user': 'root',
            'database': 'cara_libro',
            'connectionLimit': 10
        });
    }

}`